# Create 2D array with grouping/sections by day

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a plain, unsorted array of items including a `Date`.

```
struct Item {
    let itemCategory:ItemCategory
    var createDate:Date
    let id:UUID = UUID()
}

let allItems:[Item] = [
    Item(itemCategory:.sweets, date:Date().daysFromNow(days: -3)),
    Item(itemCategory:.meal, date:Date().daysFromNow(days: -1)),
    Item(itemCategory:.sweets, date:Date().daysFromNow(days: -4)),
    Item(itemCategory:.meal, date:Date().daysFromNow(days: -1)),
    Item(itemCategory:.drink, date:Date()),
    Item(itemCategory:.sweets, date:Date().daysFromNow(days: -5)),]
```

I'd like to create a version sorted by date with a second dimension used for grouping items by day. I'd like to use this 2D array as data source for a UITableView. The first dimension should inform sections, the second dimension should contain the items.

```
list = [[Item]]
```

Example hierarchy

```
Today
⌙ ...
⌙ ...
Yesterday
⌙ ...
May 3
⌙ ...
April 3
⌙ ...
```

What's a good way to create this new array?

Comment: Group the array with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`, condition `Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: $0.date)` and map the result to a custom section struct

Comment: The premise is wrong. Two dimensional array is a poor data model for a table view. Devise a row struct and make an array of that; then devise a section struct that contains the row struct array, and make an array of that. Give each struct all the info needed for display and sorting. Now build the model from the original data!

Comment: Also, if you want actual help, always provide definitions of all the types / extensions used in the question. Don't show us a _piece_ of your code and expect us to guess the rest. Provide _everything_ needed to compile your code and work out a solution for you. What is `daysFromNow`? What is ItemCategory? Sure, I can _guess_ what they might be, but why should I have to? It's _your_ code; _show_ it. Don't make us rewrite it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the proposed [[Item]] array isn't perfect for your needs, as you won't later know the date that should map for each row of items (unless you record dates separately).

Then, grouping into a Dictionary is not enough because a dictionary by date (although partially resolves the request) doesn't have its keys sorted, as (IMO) your request implies. I suggest using a simple array of tuples for output type: [(date: Date, item: [Item])]

A final caveat is that if you call Date() multiple times, it will return different date values because dates also come with time of day, and time of day obviously changes between statement executions (computers are not infinitely fast).

I fixed all the above into a [small gist](https://gist.github.com/SDolha/c44c83fc7d4cf27913cc4e60ee4b5d3b) and here is the code to return the tuples you need, with items grouped and groups sorted by descending date:

```
let sortedDates = Set(allItems.map { item in item.date }).sorted { date1, date2 in date1>date2 }
let datesWithItems = sortedDates.map { date in (date: date, items: allItems.filter { item in item.date == date }) }
```

UPDATE: You can instead use a Dictionary to collect the dates and items, but then call sorted() to return an array of tuples having the keys (i.e. dates) sorted in descending way, if you don't like the sortedDates Set approach:

```
let datesWithItems = Dictionary(grouping: allItems) { item in item.date }
    .sorted { entry1, entry2 in entry1.key > entry2.key }
```

Printing the content of datesWithItems will then have the following form (for your mock data with same Date() value):

```
2020-05-11 13:20:41 +0000
     drink
2020-05-10 13:20:41 +0000
     meal
     meal
2020-05-08 13:20:41 +0000
     sweets
2020-05-07 13:20:41 +0000
     sweets
2020-05-06 13:20:41 +0000
     sweets
```